# Tkinter events outside of the mainloop?

Tags: python, tkinter, root

The program I am writing has a tkinter window that is constantly being fed with data manually rather than being part of a mainloop. It also needs to track mouse location. I havn't found a workaround for tracking the mouse outside of mainloop yet, but if you have one please do tell.

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
import time

def getCoords(event):
    xm, ym = event.x, event.y
    str1 = "mouse at x=%d  y=%d" % (xm, ym)
    print str1

class iciclePhysics(object):
    def __init__(self, fallrange, speed=5):
        self.speed = speed
        self.xpos = random.choice(range(0,fallrange))
        self.ypos = 0

    def draw(self,canvas):
        try:
            self.id = canvas.create_polygon(self.xpos-10, self.ypos, self.xpos+10, self.ypos, self.xpos, self.ypos+25, fill = 'lightblue')
        except:
            pass

    def fall(self,canvas):
        self.ypos+=self.speed
        canvas.move(self.id, 0, self.ypos)



root = Tk()
mainFrame = Frame(root, bg= 'yellow', width=300, height=200)
mainFrame.pack()
mainCanvas = Canvas(mainFrame, bg = 'black', height = 500, width = 500, cursor = 'circle')
mainCanvas.bind("<Motion>", getCoords)
mainCanvas.pack()

root.resizable(0, 0)
difficulty = 1500
#root.mainloop()
currentIcicles = [iciclePhysics(difficulty)]
root.update()
currentIcicles[0].draw(mainCanvas)
root.update_idletasks() 
time.sleep(0.1)
currentIcicles[0].fall(mainCanvas)
root.update_idletasks() 
tracker = 0
sleeptime = 0.04


while True:
    tracker+=1
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
    if tracker % 3 == 0 and difficulty > 500:
        difficulty -= 1
    elif difficulty <= 500:
        sleeptime-=.00002
    currentIcicles.append(iciclePhysics(difficulty))
    currentIcicles[len(currentIcicles)-1].draw(mainCanvas)

    for i in range(len(currentIcicles)):
        currentIcicles[i].fall(mainCanvas)
        root.update_idletasks()

    for i in currentIcicles:
        if i.ypos >= 90:
            currentIcicles.remove(i)
    root.update_idletasks()
```

Comment: Have you tried running tkinter mainloop in a separate thread?

Answer (score 6):

There is no way. Mouse movement is presented to the GUI as a series of events. In order to process events, the event loop must be running.

Also, you should pretty much *never* do a sleep inside a GUI application. All that does is freeze the GUI during the sleep.

Another hint: you only need to create an icicle once; to make it fall you can use the `move` method of the canvas.

If you are having problems understanding event based programming, the solution isn't to avoid the event loop, the solution is to learn how event loops work. You pretty much can't create a GUI without it.